# Schengen Visa Help is required

Tags: schengen-visas

I have a week left with my Schengen visa. But I want to travel at a later date, can I apply for another schengen  visa while having this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.  The validity periods of the visas cannot overlap, but you can apply for a visa to cover a future trip during the validity period of a previous visa.